# Background color for BlackBerry SplashScreen

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I implemented a splashscreen and a mainpage for my BlackBerry app.  On the splashscreen page I want to change the background color to black.

Answer (score 2):

In the SplashScreen that you use

```
 public class SplashScreen extends MainScreen {

         public SplashScreen(){
             getMainManager().setBackground(
                      BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x00000000);
                  );
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a couple things. You could call `getDelegate().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK))` or override the Screen's paint method to

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int oldColor = graphics.getColor();
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.setColor(oldColor);
    super.paint(graphics);
}
```